# Why slow simulations when results saved into one directory?

Tags: windows, matlab, diskspace

Would love some help figuring out why a script is running much slower than it used to.
The script starts sequential Matlab simulations and saves each simulation's output to a file in a directory on computer #1. The script is running on computers #2, 3, and 4 which have the C: drive of computer #1 mounted as drive K:, and the computers read and write K:  drive files during the simulations. Prior to starting each simulation, the script saves a 'placeholder' version of the simulation's output file which later gets overwritten with that simulation's results once the simulation is complete. The output filename is unique to that simulation. The script checks for the output file before starting a simulation; if the file is found, it goes to the next simulation. The intent is to divide up many simulations among the different computers. The directory on computer #1 has many files in it (~4000, 6GB) and computer #1 is an old windows XP machine. Computers #2-4 are also windows machines and are 2+ years old.

This scheme used to work fine, saving ~3 files per minute. Now it is taking ~15 minutes per file. **What might be the leading cause for the slowdown?** Could it be the number of files in the directory or the number of computers accessing computer #1? If that is unlikely, I would like to know so I can redirect my troubleshooting.

Comment: Well, it is Windows, so maybe disk fragmentation? But there are many variables and it's not clear where the slowdown is. How big are your files? How much free space is left on computer #1? Are the other computer executing computations just as fast? Malware, Virus Scanners, Windows Update running?

Comment: Could it be that there are a lot of name collisions - how do you create the file names?

Comment: The file names are unique to each simulation. I am varying several parameters and the file name is based on the unique combination of parameters.

Comment: File sizes are 5-15MB. Computer #1 has 45GB free out of 280GB total.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the problem was an old network switch that the various computers were plugged into. When we tried a newer switch, the script ran like lightning.

However everyone's suggestions (subdirectories to reduce # of files; defragging computer #1 which turned out to be badly fragmented) were very helpful, and it was great to have some other eyes on the problem, so thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The number of items in a single directory absolutely leads to decreased performance. I've read that it depends on OS, filesystem, phase of the moon, local/remote drives ... maybe phase of the moon.

My personal rule of thumb is that at about 5,000 items per directory performance starts to degrade, and at about 10,000 performance has degraded enough that whatever you are doing will not work correctly anymore.

Comment: There are so many files in the directory that Windows won't tell me how many there are, but I am guessing it's broken 5000 files. If I make multiple subdirectories with a smaller number of files, will that keep Windows happier?

Comment: Yes. The problem is number of files in a single directory, so  subdirectories is usually the answer.

Comment: Even when I put most of the files into subdirectories, the execution time remained slow.